# VBA - Get back to a sub after opening a userform

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am struggling with a basic problem I don't find the answer online... I am trying to get back to my original sub after loading a userform (progressbar I created without using an Excel library).

The code looks like this :

**MODULE CODE :**

```
 Sub Original_Sub()

 'Some code here
     Userform1.Show
 'Some code here I can't reach

 End sub
```

**USERFORM CODE :**

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 With UserForm1

  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.35 * .Height)

 End With
 End Sub
```

The first part of the code is running properly, but it stops right after running the userform code... Why would not it continue like when I call a macro ? i.e :

```
 Call MyMacro
 'Rest of the code
```

Is there any way I can solve my problem?

Thank you in advance for your help and have a great day

Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the form modelessly. Either set its `ShowModal` property to `False`, or use:

```
Userform1.Show False
```

Comment: Thank you Rory, that was the problem. I am going to read about this.